# Using load in R markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am using Rmarkdown and knitr in RStudio. I used this code in Rmarkdown and I knit it by knitr but I cannot see the dataset in my console environment.

```
load(url("http://bit.ly/dasi_gss_data"))
```

What should I do?

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Are you getting an error message? Are not not getting what you expect (if so, what did you expect)?

Comment: Could you reword your question ... if it was really about why it wasn't in the environment reword it that way.  I don't want to edit because I'm not totally sure what the original question was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this

````
```{r}
load(url("http://bit.ly/dasi_gss_data"))
table(gss$year)
```
````

and it worked just fine.
Are you expecting to see gss in your console environment? It won't show there.

Comment: why it is not seen in my console environment?

Comment: Because it is in the knitr environment ... which is a separate one. The same reason you can't access things that are in your console environment when you run knitr.